# Not able to import module server from my testing folder

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I am writing a flask app which follows the following folder structure.

```
backend
  server.py
  __init__.py
    test
      __init__.py
      servertest.py

"""Server ping test for flask"""

import flask
import pytest
from server import app

@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    yield testing.TestClient(app)


def test_ping_resource(client):
    doc = "Flask GET service is working"
    result = client.simulate_get("/api/ping")
    assert result.status_code == 200
    assert result.json == doc
```

And this is my test file. When I am running the file. it gives

```
   from server import app
E   ImportError: No module named 'server'
```

What am I doing wrong, which is making the server module invisible to test module?

Comment: Where are you running the tests from?

Comment: Inside test folder

Comment: Try it from the root folder

Comment: Showing no test run, I am running pytest tests/

Comment: Rename `servertest.py` to `test_server.py` and run the tests from the project root dir. Also, you should review the project structure - `backend` is a package because of the `__init__.py`, so `from server import app` is the wrong import name - it should be `from backend.server import app`

Answer (score 0):

Python imports modules from a list of path:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

You have to provide Python a way to find `server.py`:

- you can run your code from the `backend` directory, because the current path is automatically happened to `sys.path` (`cd backend; pytest`)
- you can add the full path to `backend` to PYTHONPATH

At some point, you will need to read [the doc about import](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/import.html).

Also, to use pytest naturally, your test files must start with `test`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a python file, its parent folder is added to the [python path](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), but the parent of its parent (here, your root folder) is not!

What you could do is:

- running your tests from the root folder (preferred)
- Using [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/), here: `from ..server import app`
- Modify your python path (*not advised*)

Comment: How to run test from the root folder of the project. When I ran it is not able to collect test file

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html), you should only have to do `pytest tests/`...

Comment: This command is showing `collected 0 items. No tests ran in 0.00 seconds`

Comment: You should name your testing files `test_***.py`. Rename `servertest.py` to `test_server.py`